# floating spans inside ordered list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float two spans inside li. Left span will have my label where as inside the right span i'll build a graph with a nested span. I have the basic structure but chrome is placing the number at the end of the left span. How can i fix this issue?

HTML

```
<ol class="matchGraph">
                    <li>
                        <span class="leftLabel">Texas</span>
                        <span class="rightMatch"><span class="barchart" style="width: 67%"></span><span class="barchartNumber">67%</span></span>
                    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS

Parent css

```
.inner .textBlock ul, .inner .textBlock ol { margin: 0;padding-left: 20px;}
```

Items css

```
ol.matchGraph { width: auto;margin: 0;}
ol.matchGraph li {margin-bottom: 5px;}
ol.matchGraph li .leftLabel {float: left; width: 60%;display: block;}
ol.matchGraph li .rightMatch { float: right;width: 38%;display: block;}
```

And here is the display from FF, Chrome and IE

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your css at `items.css`.

```
ol.matchGraph { width: auto; margin: 0;}
ol.matchGraph li {margin-bottom: 5px;}
ol.matchGraph li .leftLabel {width: 60%; display: inline-block;}
ol.matchGraph li .rightMatch {width: 38%; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: This didn't help. Chrome is still doing the same thing.

Comment: I have switched the placement of leftLabel and rightMatch spans and then floated both right. Chrome has placed the number at the correct spot now

Comment: Theres no need to float in this particular case, just use `display: inline-block`. I tested it with Chrome and it works perfectly.
Here's an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s333858r/)